# win forms application String^ to int

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, int

I'm using Windows form application with C++.

I want to convert a `String^` to `int`.

My code is :

```
int number = std::stoi(TextBox1->Text);
```

But the error shows :

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::stoi" matches the argument list argument types are :(System:: String ^)
```

And what means `^` in front `String`?

Comment: The problem is that you think you're programming C++, while in reality you're programming in a derivative language called [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is Mircosofts managed .NET variant of C++. It's not backwards compatible with standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int number = std::stoi(std::wstring(TextBox1->Text->Data()));
```

Comment: what is Data()? the visual recognize Data() as an error @Oneiros